# Why does the solidity compiler throw a parse error on import statements? What's the workaround?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

I used npm install to install my node package dependencies. My node package dependencies look like the following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "blockcypher": "^0.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.2.4",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "^2.0.0",
    "solc": "^0.4.24"
  }
```

When I run the following compile script using node I get the following error within EVERY contract that has an import statement that references dependency in my node_modules.

I'm using Solidity Version: ^0.4.24

> Solidity Error: ParseError: Source
>   "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/ect.." not found

```js
const path = require("path"); //Delete all the contents in the build folder
const solc = require("solc"); //solidity compiler
const fs = require("fs-extra"); // Gives us access to the file system

//Require The Import Statements From The Contract
// import "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
// import "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
// import "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

//var data = require("node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.json");
//How do I use this?

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const campainPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "Contract.sol");
// const campainPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Esgro.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(campainPath, "utf8");

console.log("\n\n\t Compilation Output \n\n\n");
console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));
const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts; //Internal Error
console.log("\n\n\t Compilation Output \n\n\n");
console.log(output);

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for (let contract in output) {
  // fs.outputJsonSync(
  //   path.resolve(buildPath, contract.replace(":"", "") + ".json"),
  //   output[contract]
  // );

  console.log("\n\n\t output[contract] \n\n\n");
  console.log(output[contract]);

  fs.outputJsonSync(path.resolve(buildPath, contract), output[contract]);
}

//Compile both contracts with the solc compiler

//Write the output to the build directory
```

How do you get the compiler to "connect" with the third party dependencies on a local machine? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

the correct syntax for importing an npm dependency into a .sol file is the follows:

```
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Mintable.sol"; //You don't need to write node_modules
```

openzeppelin's documentation says:

> You need an ethereum development framework for the above import
>   statements to work!

so, probably is better that you use Truffle or Embark to compile and migrate your contract.

One last thing, OpenZeppelin uses the version ^ 0.5.0 of solidity, 
so when you go to compile remember to use a suitable version of solc.

Let me know if it worked

Comment: I'm using truffle now. I was not able to get truffle to reference the packages within node_modules. The only other workaround that I could think of was to download the entire OpenZepplin repo and compile it with my project.

Comment: I do not think you need a workaround to make it work. You simply need to correct the import. Which compilation error do you have?
This link can be helpful : https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/robust-smart-contracts-with-openzeppelin 
Maybe you can start from here.

Comment: thanks, this was key to getting mythril to run on my solidity project in hardhat. didn't realize that wasn't a solidity feature! sneaky. adding this comment to help google improve the discoverability of this answer for future users in my scenario--had to search for 'solc' errors, not issues running mythril. also: hardhat also has a 'flatten' command.